# IF functions in excel - use multiple ones with the same outcome (explained)?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, formulas

Here's my dilemma:
I have columns of colours (red, blue, etc). For each there's either 0 or 1 (1 if the item has blue in it, 0 if not). BUT there can be 2 (or 10) colours in an item. Is there a way to formulate this in Excel?

I tried using IF, but this is limiting me to 2 conditions: if the red is false, then it'd go to blue, but I cannot seem to find a simultaneous way of showing both blue and red for an item.

For example:
My skirt is both green and yellow. I have 0 for red, 0 for blue, 1 for green, 1 for yellow. I'd like this condensed in 1 column only, that would say: green, yellow (with a comma in between).

Help?

Comment: Try [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)

Comment: It's not clear at all what "formulate" means - what exactly do you want to do?  What were you trying to do with your IF formula?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing what is where, ie that `red` is in B1, the following seems to work for the example provided:

```
=LEFT(IF(B2=1,B$1&", ","")&IF(C2=1,C$1&", ","")&IF(D2=1,D$1&", ","")&IF(E2=1,E$1&", ",""),LEN(IF(B2=1,B$1&", ","")&IF(C2=1,C$1&", ","")&IF(D2=1,D$1&", ","")&IF(E2=1,E$1&", ",""))-2)
```

(Returns error where all colour flags are `0`). Most of that is stripping off the last two characters so might be better to use a helper column and two formulae (but much shorter overall).

This part:

```
=IF(B2=1,B$1&", ","")&IF(C2=1,C$1&", ","")&IF(D2=1,D$1&", ","")&IF(E2=1,E$1&", ","")
```

may be extended with further IF statements to cover more than four colours.

Were the latter version in R2 then the last two characters (comma space) may be stripped with:

```
=LEFT(R2,LEN(R2)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A VBA version (copy/paste to a regular code module in your workbook)

```
Function Colors(names, flags)
    Dim rv, i
    rv = ""
    For i = 1 To names.Cells.Count
     If flags(i) = 1 Then rv = rv & _
             IIf(Len(rv) > 0, ", ", "") & names(i)
    Next i
    Colors = rv
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=Colors($B$1:$J$1,B2:J2)
```

Assuming your color names are in `B1:J1` and first row of 1/0 is in `B2:J2`